# como incluir arquivos javascript em arquivo um arquivo javascript?

Tags: javascript

então, estou precisando incluir um arquivo javascript dentro de um arquivo javascript , mas eu não como fazer isso

ex:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

incluir arquivo.js em arquivo2.js

Comment: Se é só incluir, não tem problema copiar todo o conteúdo de `arquivo.js` e colar no topo do conteúdo do `arquivo2.js`. Agora, se precisa utilizar uma função criada no primeiro arquivo, edite sua pergunta e descreva melhor o que precisa fazer.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, não é possível fazer esse tipo de include no JS.

Porem você pode usar `import` e `export` para reutilizar código dentro de outro arquivo. Porém em uma funcionalidade do EcmaScript 6 ainda não está implementado em todos os browsers você precisa usar transpilers como Babel para funcionar

Ex.:

dado o arquivo function.js

```
function returnName(name) {
 console.log('Olá ' + name)  
}
export default returnName
```

e arquivo index.js

```
import returnName from './function'

returnName('Salatiel)
// Olá, Salatiel
```

Veja a documentação do [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) e [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)

Answer (score 0):

Para usar import e export você tem que está usando a lib do Babel, então use module.exports
module.exports é uma variável global no JS pode colocar suas funções, classes e até variáveis, para importar um módulo nesse modelo você tem que usar o require()
const minhaFunc = require(‘caminhoDoArquivo’)